# How to rearrange/move complete rows with NaN in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following `df`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 4)))
df.iloc[[3, 6, 8], :] = np.nan

print(df)

     0    1    2    3
0  4.0  1.0  9.0  3.0
1  8.0  1.0  8.0  0.0
2  0.0  6.0  5.0  6.0
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  3.0  9.0  9.0  4.0
5  1.0  5.0  5.0  3.0
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  3.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  8.0  9.0  8.0  5.0
```

I need to move all the `NaN` rows according to another boolean dataframe `nan_df`.

```
nan_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros([10, 4])).astype(bool)
nan_df.iloc[[2, 4, 9], :] = True

print(nan_df)

       0      1      2      3
0  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False
2   True   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False
4   True   True   True   True
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
7  False  False  False  False
8  False  False  False  False
9   True   True   True   True
```

I must not overwrite any row in `df`, but I need to rearrange/move the `NaN` rows. I'm expecting the following result:

```
     0    1    2    3
0  4.0  1.0  9.0  3.0
1  8.0  1.0  8.0  0.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  0.0  6.0  5.0  6.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  3.0  9.0  9.0  4.0
6  1.0  5.0  5.0  3.0
7  3.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
8  8.0  9.0  8.0  5.0
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

As a side note, the number of `NaN` in `df` and `nan_df` always matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rows in df1 that are nulls and not nulls

```
not_null = df1[df1.notna().any(1)]
nulls = df1[df1.isna().any(1)]
```

Get index labels in df2 for null and not null

```
nulls_positions = df2[df2.all(1)].index
not_nulls_positions = df2[~df2.all(1)].index
```

Index df1 with the index labels and replace the relevant rows;
(Numpy is used here, to avoid pandas aligning on the indices before inserting the values):

```
df1.loc[nulls_positions] = nulls.to_numpy()
df1.loc[not_nulls_positions] = not_null.to_numpy()
     0    1    2    3
0  4.0  1.0  9.0  3.0
1  8.0  1.0  8.0  0.0
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  0.0  6.0  5.0  6.0
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  3.0  9.0  9.0  4.0
6  1.0  5.0  5.0  3.0
7  3.0  4.0  1.0  4.0
8  8.0  9.0  8.0  5.0
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

- Drop current NaN rows from df
- Find indexes of True rows from nan_df
- Create a line of Nones
- Insert this concatenate this line by the found indexes

```
df = df.dropna()
Nan_indexes = nan_df.loc[nan_df.all(1)].index
line = pd.DataFrame({0: [None], 1: [None], 2: [None], 3: [None]})
for i in Nan_indexes.tolist():
    df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:i], line, df.iloc[i:]]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

[image: result df as asked]